# Why ${a_n^{1/n}}$ converge to 1, if ${a_n}$ converge to a a positive real.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How you prove that. Intuitive is obvious since if $a$ is bigger than 1, then you use the classical proof and if not you can bounded the number with two fractions of the form $1/n$, and the divisor goes to one, but how you actually do this?

Comment: $a >$ or you mean $a_n > 1 $ for all $n$?

Comment: I see now that this is not the right way to think about it! since whe can have for example $a_n = a + \frac{-1^n}{n}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say $a_n$ converges to $a>0$. Then choose small $\epsilon>0$ such that $a-\epsilon>0$. Then, if $n$ is large enough, we have $a-\epsilon<a_n<a+\epsilon$. Then, you have
$$(a-\epsilon)^{1/n}<a_n^{1/n}<(a+\epsilon)^{1/n}$$. Letting $n\to+\infty$, you obtain the result.